# Allow HTTP to create a file in LAMP server

Tags: php

I was trying to create a web form that would accept the data from the user and store it in a text file.

For this I have installed LAMP server and I have written the code in PHP. Now the problem is that the target file is not getting created. I googled it on different websites. Once such link says that

```
your connection (HTTP) doesn't have permission to change the text file
```

I used the following link

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?74465-Can-PHP-write-variable-content-to-text-files

I am also posting the code that I have written. I am sure that my code is correct. I suspect that the fact the file is not getting created is something to do with the configuration of LAMP server. Can anyone help me on this.

here are the codes

confirm_send.php

```
<?php

echo "your data has been successfully sent\nNow printing the last name";


$Fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$Lname = $_POST['last_name'];

echo $Lname;

$file = 'people.txt';

file_put_contents($file, $Fname);

?>
```

myform.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Input Control</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="confirm_send.php" method="post">
First name:  <input type="text" name="first_name" />
<br>
Last name:  <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the directory permissions. I think the group that the web server runs under must be able to write to the directory. Example on my similar install I added the group 'webmasters'.

Comment: You might want to path out the file to a working directory and play with the permissions there. `$file = '/test_dir/people.txt';`.

Comment: when I try to give permission to the directory, in this case /var/www/html directory, read permission is not given to me. I under www folder wrote sudo chmod 666 html/

Comment: following above task, I am not able to open the file from browser, when I type the url localhost/myform.php it says that I don't have the permission to access this file

Comment: I think that if all the directories leading up to the current must have write permissions also. Put your test directory on the root and give it 777 permissions. Then check the user that the web server uses, via php, to write the text file. Add this group recursively to the directory where you want the text file to live. This way it does not need to be 666 or 777.

Comment: Check out this answer that uses `chmod($file, 0664);` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240034/how-can-i-create-a-file-with-file-put-contents-that-has-group-write-permissions)